# Server 2012 DHCP Policies

Tags: networking, dhcp, windows-server-2012

I'm studying DHCP and Windows Server. I have a virtual SOHO inside VMware, running the following config:

```
SRV1 (Server 2012): 192.168.10.10 (Addr Reservation DHCP)
DHCP Pool: 192.168.10.1 - 192.168.10.254
Exclude from Pool: 192.168.10.1 - 192.168.10.99
Exclude from Pool: 192.168.10.200 - 192.168.10.254
```

I want all workstations that join my network to be addressed in the range `192.168.10.100 - 192.168.10.199` (100 possible IPs) and that's what I get with this config, ok. But I need to configure printers, IP Phones and others in a pre-defined range too.

What I have in mind is:

```
Printers: 192.168.10.200 - 192.168.10.219 (20 IPs)
IP Phones: 192.168.10.220 - 192.168.10.239 (20 IPs)
```

I've read that I can accomplish that using policies, but I found the config a bit confusing:

[image: DHCP Policy]

How can I config that in a way that all Printers and IP Phones get in the range I want to? The "easiest" way would be using MAC Addr, but that would require me to know every single MAC from every single Printer, IP Phone, is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about servers and enterprise networking are [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here at Super User. Your question is better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), and will likely be migrated there shortly. Please do not double-post your question!

Comment: I think if this was for a corporate IT department it'd be off topic but since they are just "studying DHCP and Windows Server" to me it IS on topic as it is "personal and home computer networking" and is not an "issue specific to corporate IT support and networks". That being said, I grant it's a fine line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you'd want to setup IP phones on separate network using [voice VLANs](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12-1_9_ea1/configuration/guide/scg/swvoip.pdf) so you can do QoS tagging.

Since it's a different network, you wouldn't need policies to separate out the voice traffic, but it may require a [DHCP Relay Agent](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc779610%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

As for printers, it is likely you don't have many different manufacturers of printers even if you have many different models.

This would be a case to use a MAC prefix for each of the manufacturers and then append a wildcard `*` to catch any model by those manufacturers.

From [Scope-level Link layer filtering using DHCP Policies in Windows Server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2012/09/15/scope-level-link-layer-filtering-using-dhcp-policies-in-windows-server-2012.aspx) what you would do is:

> On the conditions page, click on ‘Add’ and in the dialog that pops up,
>   choose the MAC address as the criteria and make sure that the operator
>   chosen is “Equals”. Now add all the MAC-addresses in the list box for
>   values. Note that this also has support for wildcards should you need
>   it. You could select a prefixed MAC address and append a wild card
>   along with selecting individual MAC-addresses.

You can obtain common prefixes by querying a MAC address database such as [coffer.com](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=canon).

You could use the same technique for IP phones as well if setting up a voice VLAN is not something you want to do.